# Insert image to reporting project into iif

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, reportingservices-2005

I would like to insert an image into this expession instead of True and False

> =IIf(Sum(Fields!cont.Value, "DataSet7")<>Sum(Fields!tot.Value,
>   "DataSet7"), True,False)

i would like to insert a red or green image to compare this two fields

thanks to all who wants to help me

Answer (score 0):

found by myself on google

insert image > tab visibility > show or hide based on a expression >

bye

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest You also to try send different picture from SQL depending on that condition, If you are able to change database and TSQL script of getting your data,
It has good and bad sides of stores also